# C# How to modify text file

Tags: c#, file, text-editor, accounts

I need to read accounts.txt and add/change number after password

Here is accounts.txt

```
user|password
user1|password1
```

After starting

```
user|password|1
user1|password1|1
```

After closing

```
user|password|0
user1|password1|0
```

Sorry for my english

Comment: In what pattern do you need these numbers? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this reference first `System.IO` Then:

For reading:

```
string[] accounts= File.ReadAllLines("accounts.txt");
//each item of array will be your account
```

For modifying :

```
accounts[0] += "|1";//this adds "|1" near password
accounts[0].Replace("|1","|0"); this will change the "|0" text to "|1"
```

And For writing:

```
File.WriteAllLines("accounts.txt",accounts);
```

Comment: This is it , but how to bypass line with |1..

Comment: @user3324218 You can pass the line with using `if()` like : `foreach(string o in accounts){ if(!o.Contains("|1"){ DoWhatYouWant(); })//this means if line not contains "|n" DoWhatYouWant(); `

Comment: Okey, thanks . I have one more question: I used accounts[5] and i exit programme so i need to change in accounts[5] (|1 to |0) but programme change (|1 to |0) in accounts[1] ...

Comment: If you Do something like `accounts[5].Replace("|1","|0");`  `accounts[1]` will not change look again your code maybe you miss or not see a code that changes `accounts[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\filepath.txt");
    List<string> newlines = new List<string>();
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
      string[] temp = line.Split('|');
      newlines.Add(temp[0] + "|" + temp[1] + "|" + "1");
    }

 File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\filepath.txt", newlines.ToArray())
```

Comment: Indeed, thx for the correction.

Comment: And the method returns an array of string `string[] lines`. But good answer though.

Comment: One more test needs to be done, specifically, if there acually is a number after the second `'|'`, it only needs to be changed instead of another number being appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `System.IO.File` class, as well as general `System.IO.Stream` and `System.IO.StreamReader` classes.

There are a bunch of examples on the internet on how to read and write text files in .NET:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)